# receive the data passed in the body of the request API Django Python

Tags: python-3.x, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I want to get the data passed in the request body like :
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5s1e.png

My function look like :

```
def test(request):
        # I want recieve data from body here like
        data = functionRequestBody
        print(data)
        return HttpResponse()
```

Comment: Try `request.body`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I edited my post it is better ?
Also request.body display this : b''

Comment: i finded !
I miss "/" at the end of my endpoint.
Thx raphael "request.body" is the good solution

Answer (score 0):

What information are you looking for? Try `request.text`, `request.session`, etc. If your app has users you can get the current user's info through `request.user`: ex `request.user.pk` returns the db entry's primary key, `request.user.username` will return username.

https://www.javatpoint.com/django-request-and-response

Comment: I edited my post . can u read again plz ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is request.body .
I find a better answer on another post StackOverflow

> ```
> body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
> request = json.loads(body_unicode)
> ```

(warning : ended your endpoint with a "/" else is not working)
Thx Raphael for your comm !